# Alert upon completion of Manifest cache with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, caching, cache-manifest

How do I alert a success message when cache.manifest has download all the files in a html5 app? (Bascially success alert on complete cache download)!

Thanks

Comment: My app is about 43 MB (Due to large png files) I need to make sure that ipad caches all the data before I go offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well thanks to the very well thought article from Garden Gnome http://gardengnomesoftware.com/wiki/Cache_Manifest_File

I found the answer. All you have to do it create a div which will display the status of cache by adding this to your page:

```
<div id="cachestatus" style="position:fixed;left: 2px;top: 2px; width: 150px;height:18px;color: #ff0000;padding: 1px 3px; opacity:1; z-index:100; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; opacity:0.2;"></div>
```

and just right after this div add the following java-script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var cacheStatus  = document.getElementById('cachestatus');
    cacheStatus.innerHTML="cache status";


    if (navigator.onLine) {
        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
            if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
                window.applicationCache.swapCache();
                cacheStatus.innerHTML="update ready!";
                if (confirm('A new version of this page is available. Reload?')) {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        }, false);
        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('cached', function(e) {cacheStatus.innerHTML="cache is ready!"; },false);
        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('noupdate', function(e) { cacheStatus.innerHTML="cache is up to date!"; },false);
        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('downloading', function(e) { cacheStatus.innerHTML="downloading..."; },false);
        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('error', function(e) { cacheStatus.innerHTML="error"; },false);
        window.applicationCache.update();
    } else {
        cacheStatus.innerHTML="offline";
    }
</script>
```

status of the cache will be displayed in the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to various events in the `window.applicationCache`object. One of them is the `updateready` event.

You will also have to make sure that any cache update is reloaded correctly for the user. Refer to the following [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) that covers Application Cache basics, its events and how to handle the updates in a programmatic way.

Some other articles that you should refer to while dealing with AppCache are:

- http://appcachefacts.info/
- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/application-cache-is-a-douchebag/